# How to find the active editarea in jquery

Tags: javascript

I am using editarea editor in content management system. In my page there are 3 editarea, so how can i find the editarea id when it is active, ie need to find in which editarea the cursor is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find with jquery

```
var id;

$("textarea").focus(function () {
     id = this.id;
});
```

or

```
var id = $("*:focus").attr("id");
```